# Get all elements of an XML with a tag starting with

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have this XML :

```
<computers>
    <computer sid="1353323295303">
        <description>TEST</description>
        <match.country result="match" value="FR EU">
            <match.country result="match" value="EU"></match.country>
        </match.country>
    </computer>
</computers>
```

How can I select all tags starting with "match."

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` method:

```
var $match = $('computers *').filter(function() {
    return this.localName.indexOf('match') === 0
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UmUkj/